# Fail to receive push notifications from Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-1.9.3.jar')
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.package.name" >

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<!-- Internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="my.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="my.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="my.package.name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

my Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, MY_APP_ID, MY_CLIENT_KEY);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                } else {
                    Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                }
             }
        });
    }
```

The message "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel." prints when the app launches. But my phone didn't receive any push notification when I used the "send push notification" feature on Parse.com.

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this problem and successfully received push notifications from Parse.com.

#### The cause:

My app will register GCM registration id upon launching because of a previous need. Therefore, after adding the Parse integration, the procedure is like below:

1. Parse automatically registers a GCM registration id from Google.
2. My app registers for a GCM registration id again.

When I used Parse.com to send a test push notification to my phone, the registration id on Parse.com is not the newest. So Parse.com didn't send the push notification.

#### The solution:

After removing the code of registering for GCM registration id, I successfully received the push notification from Parse.com.

Answer (score 0):

Do you done this process?

https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications-setting-up-push

However, as an advanced feature for developers that want to send pushes from multiple push providers, Parse allows you to optionally register your app for pushes with additional GCM sender IDs. To do this, specify the additional GCM sender ID with the following  tag as a child of the  element in your app's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
           android:value="id:YOUR_SENDER_ID" />
```